# Can't upload program to ESP8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide

I have issues loading WifiWebServer example code onto ESP8266. I am currently connecting it to an Arduino Mega 2560. I tested this code months ago and had no issues, but recently when I tried to run the code again to work on a project it doesn't work.

I even tried purchasing new ESP modules thinking that my previous one had burned out but that wasn't the case, because the new ESPs were giving me the same issue. My connection is correct, I have it on programming mode GPIO0 connected to GND and tried resetting it but nothing works.

I am using ESP8266 ESP-01S. I know there's nothing wrong with the code either because these are examples from the Arduino IDE.

I got the following errors:

> warning: espcomm_sync failed
>   error: espcomm_open failed
>   error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
>   error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there is something wrong with the way you are connecting the ESP to your laptop/pc. I am thinking you are using a FTDI adapter, an USB to TTL type of adapter, so I would first check I have the right connections in place. Depending on what adapter you use, it might look like this:

http://www.miupanel.com/portals/0/Website%20graphics/esp01_program.png?timestamp=1458163429824

If more informations on this are needed come back with more info regarding the hardware you use to upload code on the ESP and I will do my best.